# What does UNIV_HOTBACKUP mean in InnoDB source?

Tags: mysql, innodb, mariadb

I am reading source code of innodb engine. In mem_block_info_t struct, there is some pre-compile instructions, such as UNIV_HOTBACKUP. What is it means? Is it opened by default? My MySQL source code version is mariadb-10.0.14.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There used to be  in the past (maybe there is still, in some incarnation) a non-free tool called Innodb hot backup, ibbackup. It used specially compiled innodb, with this flag on. The flag is not set otherwise